# Angular interceptor should not intercept bad requests

Tags: angular, rest, http, angular-http-interceptors

I am writing a web app in Angular 8, which gets data from a .NET Core backend. It authenticates using JWT tokens, and if the token is not valid, the backend gives a `401 Not Authorized` error code. To handle this correct in Angular, I added a http interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, finalize, first, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthenticationService} from "../_services/authentication.service";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).observ((err) => {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                    this.authenticationService.logout();
                    location.reload(true);
                }

                const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;

                console.log("Hij komt als allerlaatste hier, waar de error");
                console.log(error);
         });
    }
}
```

For now this works correct. However, I am adding a register page and if the email is already in use, users should get an error. The backend gives then a response with status code `400 Bad Request`, but I want to get this error in my own code, where I sent the request, to handle user messages correctly.

I tried to use tap(), but the bad request error is catched as error by the catchError function.

How should I solve this issue correctly?

Comment: Why does the server send a `400 Bad Request`? Did the client send malformed JSON, are the headers wrong or are the query parameters of the URL wrong? A server should not send `400` for an email already in use. The server successfully handled the request and sent a response. The status should be `200`. Don't use `400`s for business logic.

Comment: @Reactgular I'm not sure for that, but maybe I could use 409 Conflict, or 422 Unprocessable Entity? Because, the result is not Okay, the client should send a new request which should be immuted I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `throwError()` from `rxJs`, so if the response is `400` you just throw an error and catch it in your `service`, so Just add 1 more if condition for `Bad Request` with error code `400` like this:

```
if (err.status === 400) {
       const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
       return throwError(error);
}
```

Comment: Right, that will work. Is it best practice, to use 400 error codes if the sent data is not correct?

Comment: yes if data voilates the request data rules then 400 should be thrown like if it requires a boolean and you send a string then 400 should be sent, you can read more about error codes and what are their purposes

Comment: `412` can be sent for precondition failed

Comment: right. If an email already is in use, when registering, I think that I should use a `409 Conflict` ?

Comment: its for you to decide, there are no hard and fast rules regarding this, whatever is best upto your understanding and business model you can do.